# Several pgp signatures for one file

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Basic options for `file.txt` sign in GnuPG is `file.txt.asc` signature.

In our workflow I need the several signatures for `file.txt` - main example is **Author** sign and **Validator** sign.

What is a best use-case for it for GnuPG ? Can I store both signatures in one `asc` file? Or I need to handle two file `file.txt.authorname.asc` and `file.txt.checkername.asc` ? Or something else?

Comment: This appears to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202508/adding-a-gpg-signature-to-an-already-signed-document

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Storing (all) signatures in the same file as the content

You really **should** use `detached` signatures and store them in separate files (see the second part of the answer for that) but it is possible to store more than one signature with `gpg` by signing an already signed document.

This assumes that:

1. There is an order in which people sign the document and the signatures will always be verified in the opposite order.
2. The document is never changed between each signing.

Let's say that we have two signing keys: `author` and `validator`, the `author` always sign the document before sending to the validator and the validator signs it once it receives it:

**Author** signs his document (`doc.txt`)

```
gpg -u author -a --clearsign doc.txt
# this results in a file called doc.txt.asc
```

The **validator** receives `doc.txt.asc`, checks that it has a valid sign from the author, and signs it with his key

```
gpg --verify doc.txt.asc
gpg -u validator -a --clearsign doc.txt.asc
# resulting in doc.txt.asc.asc
```

Now you have `doc.txt.asc.asc` a file with both signatures.  To verify both signatures you must do:

```
gpg --decrypt doc.txt.asc.asc 1>authors-file.txt.asc
gpg --decrypt authors-file.txt.asc 1>original-file.txt
```

The order of the verification **is important**.  You can chain as many signatures as needed using this method but you must follow the exact opposite order from the signing when verifying.

Note: You can use `--output` (`-o`) to change the default output file of `gpg`.

---

### Using detached signatures

The main advantage of the detached signature is that you do not need to pass the file through `gpg` to get the original (you can still read clearsigned files but you need to overlook the signature clutter).  It is advisable to use `--output` (`-o`) when constructing several detached signatures, a good naming convention for signatures helps a lot when you need to find a specific signature.

The order in which the signing or verifying happens is not important with detached signatures but i'll keep the same order from the previous section.  First the **author** signs his document `doc.txt`:

```
gpg -u author -a -o doc.author.asc --detach-sig doc.txt
```

The author sends both files `doc.txt` and `doc.author.asc` to the **validator** who verifies the signature and makes a signature of his own:

```
gpg --verify doc.author.asc doc.txt
gpg -u validator -a -o doc.validator.asc --detach-sig doc.txt
```

This time you have **three** files instead of one: `doc.txt`, `doc.author.asc` and `doc.validator.asc`.  You can verify the signatures one-by-one with:

```
gpg --verify doc.author.asc doc.txt
gpg --verify doc.validator.asc doc.txt
```

The order of verification **is not important**, and the people who need to sign this file are free to sign it in whichever order they want.

The disadvantage of this method is that you end with several files but the advantages (see below) far outweigh it.

The advantages of detached signatures for this scenario are:

1. You can allow people to modify the file during the signing.  You just need all versions of the file and need to know which signatures were made with which version of the file (yes, that needs a procedure in place).
2. If dozens of people sign the file and you do not need everyone to confirm its origin (say, if 10 out of 30 signatures match it is good enough), you can verify the file before receiving all signatures.  This might be useful if someone is on holiday and his key just expired.
3. And here, i repeat the main advantage: no clutter in the original file.  The original file can be read as is.  This might not seem appealing for plain text files, since you can read them inside a clear signed armor, but binary formats often cannot be read so easily.

---

### Reducing the number of files

Based on the comment by M.Babcock you can see from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202508/adding-a-gpg-signature-to-an-already-signed-document) that raw detached signatures can be `cat` together and still verified in that format.  That is possible because a signature has metadata about what key was used to perform it.  Also, the same can be performed with ASCII armored signatures.

For example, you can perform this:

```
echo doc1 > doc1
echo doc2 > doc2
gpg -u author -a -o doc1.author.asc --detach-sig doc1
gpg -u validator -a -o doc1.validator.asc --detach-sig doc1
gpg -u author -a -o doc2.author.asc --detach-sig doc2
gpg -u validator -a -o doc2.validator.asc --detach-sig doc2
cat *.asc > allsigs.asc
```

And verify the signatures:

```
$ gpg --verify allsigs.asc doc1
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:06 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: Good signature from "Author <author@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:22 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: Good signature from "Validator <validator@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:28 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: BAD signature from "Author <author@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:36 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: BAD signature from "Validator <validator@example.com>"

$ gpg --verify allsigs.asc doc2
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:06 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: BAD signature from "Author <author@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:22 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: BAD signature from "Validator <validator@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:28 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: Good signature from "Author <author@example.com>"
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Jun 2016 03:31:36 PM UTC using RSA key ID ........
gpg: Good signature from "Validator <validator@example.com>"
```

What `gnupg` does not know is what file the signature was made against.  Therefore you will always have at least `(<number of files> - 1) * <number of signers>` bad signatures (or more, if do not have the public keys of some of the signers).  There is not a trivial way to get around that, `gnupg` must try every sig.  Although nothing holds you from using `grep -v` on the output.

To verify that a certain user signed a file you only need a single occurrence of `Good signature from <that user>`.

Comment: Yours walkthrough is great! Thank you! But I think I've got the equal count of files in both scenarios.

Comment: @Y.N - Based on the comment by M.Babcock I have extended the answer.  To make that solution into an easily usable tool some scripting is needed but, i believe, that is as far as we can bend `gnupg` itself.

Comment: Somewhere on the gnupg mailing list is an explanation of how to concatenate non-detached signatures as well.  I'm not able to find it with a quick search, but it can be done.  It's easiest to manage on things that were signed with --clearsign for obvious reasons.

Comment: Any idea if this is possible with signed Git commits? We pair-program, and in regulated customers it'd be good to be able to cryptographically prove that both the committer and author were present.

Comment: @EngineerBetter_DJ - If I'm not mistaken `git commit -S` simply appends the signature to the end of `-m` (that's what `-s` for tags does at least).  You could just append two signatures to `-m` yourself instead.  For automation you would need to wrap `git commit` and `git log` yourself to call `gpg` on both.  But then again, that is what `git` does anyway for a single sig.